# How to Return a List of Values from a Dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have created a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{100000: (400, 'Does not want to build a %SnowMan %StopAsking', ['SnowMan', 'StopAsking'], [100, 200, 300], [400, 500]), 
100001: (200, 'Make the ocean great again.', [''], [], [400]), 
100002: (500, "Help I'm being held captive by a beast!  %OhNoes", ['OhNoes'], [400], [100, 200, 300]), 
100003: (500, "Actually nm. This isn't so bad lolz :P %StockholmeSyndrome", ['StockholmeSyndrome'], [400, 100], []), 
100004: (300, 'If some random dude offers to %ShowYouTheWorld do yourself a favour and %JustSayNo.', ['ShowYouTheWorld', 'JustSayNo'], [500, 200], [400]), 
100005: (400, 'LOLZ BELLE.  %StockholmeSyndrome  %SnowMan', ['StockholmeSyndrome', 'SnowMan'], [], [200, 300, 100, 500])}
```

I'm trying to return the list of strings that include a given tag, where my dictionary is of the form `{string_id: (user_id, string, tags, likes, dislikes)}`.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
    for items in value:
        if items == value[2]:
            tagged_chirps = [value[1]]
return tagged_chirps
```

However, when I run this for the tag "SnowMan", the function returns only:

```
['LOLZ BELLE.  %StockholmeSyndrome  %SnowMan']
```

Instead of what I want it to return, which would be:

```
['Does not want to build a %SnowMan %StopAsking', 
    'LOLZ BELLE.  %StockholmeSyndrome  %SnowMan']
```

Does anyone know why my function would only be returning one of the strings instead of all the strings desired?

Comment: `tagged_chirps` is only ever a list of a single item. `tagged_chirps = [value[1]]` - what if it already *had* a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate list, you need to create a list, then add to it.

```
tagged_chirps=[]
for key, value in mydict.items():
    if 'SnowMan' in value[2]:
        tagged_chirps += [value[1]]
print(tagged_chirps)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for your dictionary:

```
def get_string(dict,tag):
    result=[]
    for el in mydisct:
        if tag in mydisct[el][2]:
            result.append(mydisct[el][1])
    return result

print get_string(mydisct,'SnowMan')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a list comprehension to construct your list of strings:

```
tag = 'SnowMan'

strings = [v[1] for k,v in my_dict.items() if tag in v[2]]
```

Returns:

```
['Does not want to build a %SnowMan %StopAsking', 'LOLZ BELLE.  %StockholmeSyndrome  %SnowMan']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
tag = 'SnowMan'
res = [string for user_id, string, tags, likes, dislikes in my_dict.values() if tag in tags]
```

Returns:

```
['Does not want to build a %SnowMan %StopAsking', 'LOLZ BELLE.  %StockholmeSyndrome  %SnowMan']
```